# Disable tkinter menu option until another one has been fully executed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a simple script using tkinter that allows the user to load a csv file into a dataframe via a menu option. Once it's selected, the contents are printed to the screen. Then another option under the same menu plots the dataframe. I'm confused as to how I go about disabling the plot option until the dataframe is actually loaded. My example thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog,Menu

root = Tk()

def _open():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "Users/fishbacp/Desktop",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("csv","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    df=pd.read_csv(root.filename)
    print(df)

def _plotdf():
    df.plot()
    plt.show()

def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
filemenu.add_command(label="Plot", command=_plotdf) 
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

I realize

```
filemenu.entryconfig('Plot',state='disabled')
```

will disable the plot button. But I'm confused as to whether it could be incorporated for my purposes.

Comment: if the loading happens in the same thread there shouldn't be such issues since it will be impossible to press that button anyways because plotting may block the mainloop

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. As written, the code above will throw an "Exception in Tkinter callback" message when I select "Plot" before actually opening a file.  (It still lets me open a file after making such a mistake though.)

I think the end user would find it more helpful if I disable the plot button until a file is actually loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. Since the print function is called only after dataframe is loaded, the menu option are enabled and disabled after it.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


root = Tk()

def _open():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "Users/fishbacp/Desktop",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("csv","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    global df
    df=pd.read_csv(root.filename)
    print(df)
    filemenu.entryconfig("Open",state="disabled")#==Disable Menu Option
    filemenu.entryconfig("Plot",state="normal")#==Enable Menu Option

def _plotdf():
    
    df.plot()
    plt.show()
    filemenu.entryconfig("Plot",state="disabled")#==Disable Menu Option
    filemenu.entryconfig("Open",state="normal")#==Enable Menu Option
    

def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
filemenu.add_command(label="Plot", command=_plotdf) 
filemenu.entryconfig("Plot",state="disabled") #==Disable Menu Option
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. I did notice with the above code though that when I hit the Plot option, the file dialog opened again. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Try moving the ```filemenu.entryconfig``` part above the line ```plt.show()```

Comment: That didn't correct the problem. The file dialog opened simultaneously with the plot when "Plot" was selected.

Comment: That is not happening in my case. The try replacing ```root.filename``` to simply ```filename```

Comment: Interesting. I'm using python 3.9 and tkinter 8.6 on a Mac running Big Sur. I should have mentioned this in my original post. I'll keep persisting. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, once you solve your problem, please tell me